# Code style: "hiding" data types (Java)

Tags: java, types, conventions

I'm working on a set of classes to represent musical notes, bars, rhythms and so on. Naturally, I'll have to deal with time signatures that are best represented by a fraction (like 4/4, 3/4 and so on).

I'm wondering what is better style. Having a constructor for a Bar contain a Fraction-object or just two ints as a time signature.

```
public Bar(Fraction timeSignature) {
    this.timeSignature = timeSignature;
}
```

or:

```
public Bar (int num, int den) {
    timeSignature = new Fraction(num, den);
}
```

I mean… i could have both but which one should I go for in my application? Is there a "better" style?

Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: My preference is to provide more flexibility to users, so I would say both. You can also look at the usage and determine what would be most nature and go  with that single signature.

Comment: Why not more OO-approach?  Why not create a TimeSignature Object?

Comment: Ok i'll go for 2nd one. Because i think that passing int is much efficient then objects. Well i'm not sure, expert advice is better.

Comment: @gtgaxiola then the same question would apply to the TimeSignature-object.

Comment: @Arpit Worrying about efficiency at that point is pointless.

Comment: @Arpit but it is less comprehensible, and from the context, it seems that this will never cause real performance problems... Not to mention that in my opinion this counts as premature optimization...

Comment: @Nomin hmmm. ok But can you tell me i'm right or wrong. :P

Comment: @Arpit You aren't ever passing the object in java, you're passing a reference to the object. You therefore won't ever really be able to tell the difference between the two calls. Granted when you pass the reference to the object you need to have created it before, which of course takes some x amount of time. That amount of time is trivial for something as simple as that object and not really worth talking about, but would in all likelihood take longer than assigning to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with every design question, this depends. In this case, you should consider how your class is going to be used.

In general, I prefer simpler APIs. Compare this:

```
Bar myBar = new Bar(4, 4);
```

to this:

```
Bar myBar = new Bar(new Fraction(4,4));
```

The latter alternative is more explicit (which is good), but might become tedious if you instantiate a lot of bars with literal arguments. On the other hand, if your Code needs to handle Fractions anyway, the first syntax might be better.

Another aspect to consider is the overhead of introducing the new class `Fraction`. Creating an additional class just to store two `int`s means a lot of overhead for little use. However, if `Fraction` provides other services as well (such as simplification of fractions), the class earns its right to exist.

Comment: I just noticed that I missed the fact that you create a `Fraction` in both cases. If you want the Fraction anyway, just look at what feels better (explicity vs. tediousness) in the places where the constructor is called.

Comment: I can't decide. :D But I really like the look of `new Bar(4, 4)`. So you would say it's ok to use both constructors throughout my project?

Comment: I'd keep things simple and just define the one you like more. If you later notice that you absolutely need another constructor, you can still add it. As a general rule of thumb, you should only ever add a method to a class when you are going to call it from somewhere else. Methods that are never called just clutter up your source files and make the project harder to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts, this helped out a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd go w/ the first approach.  If you know you need/want a Fraction object, why have the Bar not just take that?  The person invoking the Bar class will need to understand the Fraction either way (to pass you the ints), so it's just cleaner.

Comment: +1 I would prefer the first if Fraction is immutable.  If for some reason it cannot be, I would take a copy like the second example.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use the first one and provide a factory method in the fraction class to be able to call something like:

```
new Bar(Fraction.of(4, 4));
```

best of both world ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I'll be going with that. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, simple APIs are nice, yes, but if you expand the constructor later to take more parameters (say, BPM), using primitives rather than objects makes the calling code harder to understand.  i.e.:

```
Bar myBar = new Bar(4, 4) // Okay
Bar myBar = new Bar(4, 4, 120) // ??
Bar myBar = new Bar(new TimeSignature(4, 4), 120) // Much clearer
```

When in doubt, explicit is better.

Secondly, I would say *don't* store the time signature in a `Fraction` object -- while they are often written as though they are fractions, time signatures are not.  3/4 and 6/8 are equivalent as fractions, but are different time signatures that produce a different sound as a result.  `TimeSignature` is within your program's domain, it warrants a custom type.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that 3/4 == 6/8 in the math domain, but not in the music domain, hence Fraction is probably a bad name.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider making time signature an enum in order to prevent user input error. Since you may have a finite  set of time signatures(2/4, 6/8, 4/4) you can control the time signatures a user creates by doing the following:

```
//example
new Bar(TimeSignature.DUPLE_2_2)

public enum TimeSignature{

DUPLE_2_2(2,2), QUADRUPLE_2_4(2,4), TRIPLE_3_4(3,4);

private final int numerator;
private final int denominator;

private TimeSignature(int numerator, int denominator) {
this.numerator = numerator;
this.denominator = denominator;
}


}
```

Good Luck

Comment: +1 nice idea - although some people fight hard to find new exotic systems and a static collection of possible values is maybe not the best option. But that depends on the use case.

Comment: Atif, thank you for your thoughts. This looks interesting. While it's not suited for my project because I'll have to many time signatures available to the user, I'm going to keep this in mind for future projects where it might come in handy. Thank you!